# Custom loss function Keras backend

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, classification

I'm getting stuck at implementing a custom loss function that should measure the Recall of the classified data.

for a more detailed problem description, see:
[Classification: skewed data within a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48880273/classification-skewed-data-within-a-class)

I have implemented it with numpy arrays, but how would one translate this to Keras-backend? Does anyone have an idea?

```
# Try Recall for the loss
def customLoss(yTrue,yPred):
   true_positives = np.sum(np.logical_and(yPred, yTrue))
   total = np.sum(np.sum(yTrue))
   return true_positives/total
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apart from the fact that the numpy implementation is one of recall, not precision, I'd suggest taking a look at https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/losses.py .

Comment: thanks, I updated it!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using numpy, we must use tensorflow math library which deals with tensor. You can find an example of the maths on the following link: [tf.reduce_sum()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_sum).

You must be careful with the datatype of the tensor elements. The tf.logical_and function only accept boolean inputs, so  yTrue and yPred must be converted to boolean values. Since you want a float output, it is recommended to convert the output of the logical_and operation to dtype of float.

Your custom loss function should look like this (more or less):

```
import tensorflow as tf
def customLoss(yTrue,yPred):
    # Convert yPred and yTrue to boolean
    yPred_bool = tf.equal(yPred > 0.5, True)
    yTrue_bool = tf.equal(yTrue > 0.5, True)    
    # Count number of true positive labels
    true_positives = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.logical_and(yPred_bool, yTrue_bool),dtype=tf.float32), axis=0)
    # Count number of positive labels
    total = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast((yTrue > 0.5),dtype=tf.float32),axis=0)
    return true_positives/total
```

Hope it is useful. Cheers!